# Wakelock not working on Android

Tags: android, wakelock

I am doing a Android app similar to Runkeeper. When I start the app I start a thread for the clock, and I also have onLocationChanged updates for gps. Everything works fine when the screen is on, but when the screen is off the clockthread stops.

I have tried with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK but nothing happened. 
Here is the the code from the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

and here is the code

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
```

and in onCreate()

```
PowerManager pm=(PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl=pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"my wakelock");
    wl.acquire();
```

have also tried

```
PowerManager pm=(PowerManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl=pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"my wakelock");
    wl.acquire();
```

I don't know why the the clockthread is stopped when I have WAKE_LOCK. The clockthread is started when I press a button in a butttonlistener if that can be a part of a explenation? Anyone have any suggestions
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happened"?  What do you expect to happen?  How do you know that it didn't?

Comment: Hi.  What i expect is that the running thread that handle the clock Will keep running but it closes down when the screen sleep. That clockthread is being startad by a buttonlistener method.

Comment: Ok.  What do you mean by "clockthread"?  Are you referring to something in your app or something in the system?

Comment: With clockthread i mean a startbutton that from thé buttonlistener start a New thread that will count System.currentTImeMillis and work as a timer/clock för the app. That timer/clock-thread is running in a while (timerIsRunning==true)-loop untill the stopbutton is pressed and the whilecondition is set to false. When the phonescreeen is turning off the thread is stop running. My problem is that i need the thread to keep running when phone is in sleep. Maybe it is bettet with some kind of service?

Comment: Got it.  Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what a Wakelock does.  A wakelock keeps the device active (think CPU running) while your program holds it.  Here are some things it doesn't do:

- Control the lifecycle of any thread in your application process
- Control the lifecycle of your *application*!!

In fact, Android is absolutely guaranteed to stop your application, eventually, no matter what you do.  When that happens, you disconnect from the `PowerManager` and your wakelock is automatically released.

You might want the [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: Thanks för the help!